# How to trace problem of application not starting in Linux?

Tags: opensuse, application, trace

I have opensuse leap 15.0.   I installed a libero soc application from microsemi.  It is giving me a bizarre problem.  When installed libero soc v12, after clicking its desktop icon, it starts normally (flash screen and an expected error message that some license files are missing etc).  However I cannot use it for my board kit programming because my board is much older and v12 version does not support older boards.  So I installed appropriate libero soc v11.9.  However, when I click its desktop icon, it will not start.  It only pops the icon on menu bar and vanishes.  No flash screen and no any error messages.   How do I trace (in linux terminal or alternatively )the start up error messages so I can find out where the source of failure is?

Comment: Can you start it from the terminal? If you do that, it often will output the errors into the terminal emulator and you can go from there.

Comment: Finally I figure out the command to execute desktop file in terminal. I typed `exo-open  Microsemi-Libero_SoC_v11.9.desktop`
and get the message  `Error: Could not locate the Motif library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341044/ldd-cant-find-library-in-ld-library-path) may be relevant. I've never faced this problem.

Comment: Yes, the link you provided is very useful and confirms my problem that it is probably impossible solve.  I used yast to install motif libraries, however they are 64-bit but libero needs 32-bit.  It is impossible to find for opensuse 15.0.  Nevertheless I am still looking.